# How to save Multiple selected value from dropdown list

Tags: php

I m trying to save dropdown's multiple value in database.e.g There is two table site and sitecontact.Here between tables there are one to many relationship.Now I want to save multiple contacts for one site in database.For this In UI there is dropdown list from where user can select multiple value.I dont know how to store this value in database.I dont want to add multiple value in one field.

```
 siteID      Conatct_name
----------------------------
  3          sam,kreya,xyz
```

I want them like this way

```
siteID      Conatct_name
----------------------------
  3          sam
  3          kreya
  3          xyz
```

Comment: Its very hard to understand your problem, use spaces new lines, comma, and sample data, code etc to make your question clearer

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve by following table structure.

For your table "site" the structure may be

```
id   sitename  status
1      ex-1      1
2      ex-2      1
3      ex-3      1
```

For table "sitecontact" structure will be

```
id  site_id   contacts  status
1     1         765567     1
2     1         788556     1
3     3         6878788    1
4     2         5767887    1
5     2         8876878    1
```